# visNetwork/visLegend colors don't match

Tags: r, rstudio

I am making a plot in RStudio like this:

```
library(visNetwork)
palette("default")
nodes<-data.frame(id=rep(1:10, 1), group=rep(1:5,2), color=rep(c("red","green", "blue", "black", "cyan"), 2))
nodes$label <- nodes$id
edges <- data.frame(from=round(runif(10)*10, 0), to=round(runif(10)*10, 0), arrows="to")
graphPlot <- visNetwork(nodes, edges, main = "System Dependency Diagram")
visLegend(graphPlot, stepY=25)
```

When the legend and graph are drawn, the categories are correct, but the legend colors are different than those on the graph. I have tried assigning a specific palette to nodes and edges with the same result.

Comment: Which packages are you using? Can you provide some reproducible code?

Comment: code added above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities in `visLegend` :

1 - use groups definition, (Default). In this case, all groups parameters have to be set using `visGroups` rather than directly in nodes data.frame

```
library(visNetwork)
palette("default")
nodes<-data.frame(id=rep(1:10, 1), group=rep(1:5,2))
nodes$label <- nodes$id
edges <- data.frame(from=round(runif(10)*10, 0), to=round(runif(10)*10, 0), arrows="to")
graphPlot <- visNetwork(nodes, edges, main = "System Dependency Diagram") %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "1", color = "red") %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "2", color = "green") %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "3", color = "blue") %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "4", color = "black") %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "5", color = "cyan") %>%
  visLegend(stepY=25)
graphPlot
```

1 - Define a custom legend

```
library(visNetwork)
palette("default")
nodes<-data.frame(id=rep(1:10, 1), group=rep(1:5,2), color=rep(c("red","green", "blue", "black", "cyan"), 2))
nodes$label <- nodes$id
edges <- data.frame(from=round(runif(10)*10, 0), to=round(runif(10)*10, 0), arrows="to")

lnodes <- data.frame(id = 1:5, label = c(1:5), color = c("red","green", "blue", "black", "cyan")) 

visNetwork(nodes, edges, main = "System Dependency Diagram") %>%
  visLegend(useGroups = FALSE, addNodes = lnodes, stepY=25)
```